# How to find failing file?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm running a U-SQL job which extracts data from 7400 files and I get a "E_RUNTIME_USER_ROWTOOBIG: Row size exceeds the maximum allowed size of 4194304 bytes" error. Is there any information about which file is causing the job to fail? I can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working on adding this information to the error message. Until then you have to use the VisualStudio tooling in the following (convoluted) way (there may be other ways, but that's the approach I use).

The error message will tell you which vertex failed (e.g., SV1_EXTRACT[45]). Open the job view of the job and then select the Vertex Execution View. Then look for the line for the specific vertex. If it is an extract vertex you should be able to see the input file size. Since we currently do not split files provided in file sets, you now can take the input file size and look through your 7400 files in the ADLS data explorer for the file of the given size (Ordering the files based on size helps :)).

Please feel free to also add/vote for a better error message at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback if you have not done so already.

Thanks
Michael